# When I Change Value In varibale , those varible can't change their value it's hold old value as it as in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, variables

I am trying to change value of the instance varible in flutter but they not changed.

First I declare double type varible **SPI** with intial Value 0.0 but after i assigen new value on variable **SPI** they not change. Spi show 0.0 not new value they I reassigned In flutter.

Pleas Help me in this situation , How can i change the value of the variable in flutter.

Here My code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CPI_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  double SPI = 0.0;

  double method() {
    SPI = 16;
    return SPI;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            "$SPI",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In output I show 0.0 but I expected 16.0.

Answer (score 0):

**Stateless can't refresh value**

```
class CPI_Page extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<CPI_Page> createState() => _CPI_PageState();
}

class _CPI_PageState extends State<CPI_Page> {
  double SPI = 0.0;

   method() {
    setState((){
      SPI = 16;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "$SPI",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(onPressed: ()=> method(), child: Text("Change Value"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edited**
*This code is definitely working you can copy edited code and run on [Dart Pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1)*

```
// Copyright (c) 2019, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int SPI = 0;

   method() {
    setState((){
      SPI = 16;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "$SPI",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(onPressed: ()=> method(), child: Text("Change Value"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After converting to the Stateful Widget Problem not slove, it's showing 0.0 not a 16

Comment: Edited code you can run on dart pad.